# Progress View doesn't show on second + load when trying to do pagination SwiftUI

Tags: xcode, swiftui, pagination

Progress View doesn't show on second + load when trying to do pagination. When I scroll to the bottom the progress view will appear once. But all the other times it doesn't. This only seems to occur when im using some sort of animation.

If I just have a static text like "Loading..." it works as expected. I added the section group where it checks a condition to verify if it should be presented or not. Not sure if I'm supposed to use something like "stop animating" like the loading indicator has in UIKit

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var movies: [Movie] = []
    @State var currentPage = 1
    @State private var isLoading = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Section {
                    
                } header: {
                    Text("Top Movies")
                }
                
                ForEach(movies) { movie in
                    HStack(spacing: 8) {
                        AsyncImage(url: movie.posterURL, scale: 5) { image in
                            image
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                .frame(width: 100)
                                .cornerRadius(10)
                        } placeholder: {
                            ProgressView()
                                .frame(width: 100)
                        }
                        
                        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                            Text(movie.title)
                                .font(.headline)
                            Text(movie.overview)
                                .lineLimit(5)
                                .font(.subheadline)
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        .padding(.top, 10)
                    }
                    .onAppear {
                        Task {
                            //Implementing infinite scroll
                            if movie == movies.last {
                                isLoading = true
                                currentPage += 1
                                movies += await loadMovies(page: currentPage)
                                isLoading = false
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                Section {
                    
                } footer: {
                    if isLoading {
                        HStack {
                            Spacer()
                            ProgressView()
                                .tint(.green)
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    } else {
                        EmptyView()
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Movies")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .listStyle(.grouped)
            .task {
                movies = await loadMovies()
            }
            .refreshable {
                movies = await loadMovies()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

even when I look at the view hierarchy its like the progress view square is there but the icon / loading indicator isn't showing:
[image]

If I add the overlay modifier it works but I don't like doing this because when I scroll back up before the content finishes loading the spinner is above the list view:?

```
    .overlay(alignment: .bottom, content: {
        if isLoading {
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                ProgressView()
                    .tint(.green)
                Spacer()
            }
        } else {
            EmptyView()
        }
    })
```

Comment: I notice this bug only appear on `iOS16` !,
`iOS 15` and `iOS 14` not have this issue, you can try change `ProgressView` with `Text`, it will always appear so this issue only with `ProgressView`

Comment: yeah having a text I noticed will always make it appear

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We also had this problem, we think it is a bug of ProgressView. Our **temporary** correction is to identify the ProgressView with a unique id in order to render it again.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var id = 0

    var body: some View {
        ProgressView()
            .id(id)
            .onAppear {
                ...
                id += 1
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks mate, it is perfectly working now.

Comment: this will break you app in iOS 17, iOS 16 is working fine

Comment: Hi @Basel, we have retested our solution on iOS 17 and it continues to work as on iOS 16.
What breaks in your code?

Comment: Hi, on my app I use ProgressView on loading and on pagination, after I tried my app on Xcode 15 and iOS 17 simulator and real device, I got black screen, after I remove id and onAppear, the app working fine but progress not appear everytime some (issue as this question), when I switch to UIKit version of progressView without have id and onAppear, the app working fine and it progress appear on both ios16 and ios17

Answer (score 0):

I tried Alex slution it working fine in iOS 16 but on iOS 17 it break my code

But this will work in both iOS 16 and iOS 17

```
struct ActivityIndicator: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var isAnimating: Bool
    let style: UIActivityIndicatorView.Style

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<ActivityIndicator>) -> UIActivityIndicatorView {
        return UIActivityIndicatorView(style: style)
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIActivityIndicatorView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<ActivityIndicator>) {
        isAnimating ? uiView.startAnimating() : uiView.stopAnimating()
    }
}
```

used

```
    ActivityIndicator(isAnimating: .constant(true), style: .medium)
```